# Application fails when setting background image of JPanel to TILED

Tags: java, swing, width, background-image, jpanel

I am using the [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) class for background images on my JPanels. So far I have succeeded in Gradients, SCALED images and ACTUAL images but if I set the style of the background to TILED, the Desktop Application fails/crashes, it opens but the window is empty (see through) and I have to Stop the application to close it. I am not getting any errors in my console.

**Here is the Custom Code on my JPanel:**

```
jPanel2 = new BackgroundPanel(imgHeader, BackgroundPanel.TILED);
```

**My image is defined earlier on:**

```
final Image imgHeader = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/images/headerBar.gif"));
```

I added logging statements to the Background Panel class

```
private void drawTiled(Graphics g) {
    Dimension d = getSize();
    int width = image.getWidth(null); // returning as -1. should be 1
    int height = image.getHeight(null); // returning as 48. Correct!

    for (int x = 0; x < d.width; x += width) {
        System.err.println("outer for imgW" + width + " panelW " + d.width + " newW " + x);
        for (int y = 0; y < d.height; y += height) {
            g.drawImage(image, x, y, null, null);
            System.err.println("inner for" + height);
        }
    }
}
```

I found that *width* = **-1** therefor causing an endless loop. The width of the image is actually 1 pixel. The height (48 pixles) is correct. I got the same result when I changed the width of the image to 48 pixels.

More Tests: When I set the width to 48, the height returns -1.

Why is the image width returning as -1?

Comment: It's probably going to be difficult to solve this without any error messages. You might want to add log statements at various parts of your code to get an indication where it fails.

Comment: @THelper Added log statements and updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the java [api](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getWidth%28java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29):

> **Returns:** the width of this image, or -1 if the width is not yet known.

---

To resolve the problem you could use [ImageIO.read(InputStream)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29). It will fully read the image (creating an [`BufferedImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)).

```
final Image imgHeader = 
         ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/headerBar.gif"));
```

You can then use the `image.getWidth()` and `image.getHeight()` methods to get the size of the image.